# Liking Post Redirects To A Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is it possible to have someone like a post (not a page) on facebook and have them redirect to another page? If I created a post telling people to like my page, I would like it to either automatically like the page if they like the post, or redirect them to the page if they like my post. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just share the page as a post?

Answer (score 0):

No.  If a user wants to visit your page or like your page they should make that decision themselves.  Its not your decision to make.